# Label not accessible in code view

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I did type runat="server" in the label tag. its still not accessible.

I did copy this label from another webform. I've noticed when copying labels from others webforms, sometimes they are not accessible. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your designer code and see if its in there.  If its not your markup and designer are out of sync unless of course you have the control in a template.  I have ran into this issue recently and fixed it by just adding a literal control forcing the designer to regen and then deleting the literal.

Comment: You can also add it into designer manually. Just check the code inside designer and you will know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

from what you have given here, I see you typed runat=server without quotations.

try adding quotations and check again.

```
runat="server"
```

full example

```
<asp:label runat="server" ID="Label1" >Label1</asp:Label>
```

Comment: They are enclosed in quotation marks. Its just that I didnt mention that in the question sorry.

Comment: ok, quickly link the entire label's code. It must be something like

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1">Label</Label>

Answer (score 0):

It's because your code behind class is missing reference to that control. You guess you dont have .designer with your page class, right? Then you have to "map" that control manually

YOu can definie class variable like `Label myLabel` and then later in `Page_Load` you have to use `myLabel = Find('myLabelId')` function, to map that label. (This might not be 100% accurate syntax).

Edit: Asuming your label has ID="Label2", code should look like:

```
Label _label2;

Page_Load(  
// some code
_label2 = (Label)FindControl("Label2");
)
```

Comment: So unless I create a label using the designer view, I cant access that lebel in the code view. I am manually creating the label in the source of the aspx file

Comment: Exactly. When you have designer, it automatically creates reference for you in that 'designer' code file.

Comment: But when i do a clean solution, it removes the reference from the designer code file. Why is that?

Comment: Don't know. The reference is probably missing something that you didn't add or desginer is adding it to some other place (which I don't know). I am used to manual mapping in codebehind.